# Developing a TurnBasedMultiplayer Game

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am developing a game for android that is similar to an Instant Messaging system. So I decided to use TurnBasedGame for it. I have a few questions related to it :

1. Are there any limitations, apart from the 128kb limit, which would make somebody not want to use it.
2. The developer guide dont seem to say anything about not using the default UI for current game management (selection, mute, dismiss, etc).

It would really help if somebody could say something about google play games with custom UI ( especially current games, notification handling etc)

Comment: Your second question is a double-negative. What are you trying to ask exactly? https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/playservices_unity#1 Most games on Android are written in Unity3D, although most of them will still use the Android NotificationManager for displaying notifications. In Android, there are usually multiple ways of doing the same thing. Just pick the way that feels the easiest to you whether you make your game with standard Android UI layouts, or with Unity3D scenes, or with something else entirely.

Comment: I am not using Unity though. I would like to implement a custom game picker activity

Comment: So create a custom game picker activity, where are you getting stuck exactly? If you don't know how to program some the most basic concepts in Android, you should probably start with a simpler project that doesn't even require an internet connection to begin with. Don't try to run before you can walk.

Comment: That is exactly my question. I am sorry,but I was unable to find docs on creating a gamepicker activity

Comment: Yes, and that was exactly my answer. Your knowledge is too basic. Figure out another simpler project to start with. You don't say what your game picker activity will even look like.

Comment: It will look and behave similarly to Google's default current games activity.I just want to know how to implement my own instead of calling Google's games chooser using their intent. I am sorry for being vague. I just don't know what information to provide you with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82626/discussion-between-stephan-branczyk-and-harvey-slash).